# What should I use for model selection: AIC or p-values?

Tags: r, model

I currently have two poisson regression models: one is the main effects model (`poisson1`) whereas the other is the interaction model (`poisson1i`). When I print out the summary using R, I get the following:

```
> poisson1=glm(V3~V2+log(V4)+V5,family=poisson)
> summary(poisson1)
    Call:
    glm(formula = V3 ~ V2 + log(V4) + V5, family = poisson)
    
    Deviance Residuals: 
        Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
    -3.6005  -1.2152   0.4824   1.0132   1.8007  
    
    Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
    (Intercept) -26.6424     3.0840  -8.639  < 2e-16 ***
    V2            1.7702     0.1542  11.478  < 2e-16 ***
    log(V4)       2.4352     0.2270  10.727  < 2e-16 ***
    V5            1.6991     0.3548   4.789 1.68e-06 ***
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
    
    (Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)
    
        Null deviance: 644.269  on 9  degrees of freedom
    Residual deviance:  25.576  on 6  degrees of freedom
    AIC: 88.644
    
    Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
    
    > poisson1i=glm(V3~V2+log(V4)+V5+V2*log(V4)*V5,family=poisson)
    > summary(poisson1i)
Call:
glm(formula = V3 ~ V2 + log(V4) + V5 + V2 * log(V4) * V5, family = poisson)

Deviance Residuals: 
       1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9  
-0.18821   0.27417  -0.17428   0.07463  -0.01969  -0.23669   0.27604  -0.13648   0.01482  
      10  
 0.01306  

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)     4.97196   29.09843   0.171    0.864
V2             -1.29138    3.38826  -0.381    0.703
log(V4)        -0.01606    2.68444  -0.006    0.995
V5            -10.40090   23.13696  -0.450    0.653
V2:log(V4)      0.07252    0.26893   0.270    0.787
V2:V5           0.12538    2.20347   0.057    0.955
log(V4):V5      0.71420    2.17130   0.329    0.742
V2:log(V4):V5   0.15821    0.17321   0.913    0.361

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 644.26899  on 9  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:   0.29816  on 2  degrees of freedom
AIC: 71.366

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 3
```

As you can see, `poisson1i` has a lower AIC but I'm hesitant to say this is the best model because none of the p-values are significant. Is it still alright to use `poisson1i`?

Comment: The residual deviance is much lower for the second model, suggesting it better predicts the dependent variable.  This is probably driving the lower AIC value (even though there are more terms in the model).   I'm guessing some of the independent variables are correlated, making the p values relatively large.   If you are using a specific criterion to choose the model (like AIC), I would suggest trying some models "in between" these.  That is, with some interactions, but not all.

Comment: What are your criteria for a "best model"?